# Using cvLine on OpenCV video capture

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I have been able to stream video but what I would like to do is use cvLine to draw a line on the video as it is being recorded.  Is there anyway to do this?  cvLine seems to only work on static images.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to capture each frame, draw whatever you like on it, and perform any additional processing as you need, and save the result processed frame.